# Regex: Match numeric values after an element in html

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following html:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <span class="hello-style" id="hello123">
        hello world
     </span>
     <span class="value-style">
        1000
     </span>
     <span class="value-style">
        2000
     </span>
     <span class="value-style">
        3000
     </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to match each value after `<span class="value-style">` that can be anything, so the output from the above example should be:
1000
2000
3000

This should at least remove all non-numeric values, but it does not: 
`curl 127.0.0.1/index.html | sed 's/[a-zA-Z]/""/'`

**EDIT**

`curl 127.0.0.1/index.html | tr -d '\n' | sed '...'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3772221

Comment: Well, even after removnig all line breaks so it all appears like a simple string (see my edit) it should be possible to match the values after span elements with class "value-style":  `<span class="value-style">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/<\/span/{f=0} f; /<span class="value-style"/{f=1}' file

    1000
    2000
    3000
```

extract lines between the patterns.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly does `/<\/span/{f=0} f;` and the section after the semi colon in the awk-command?  Does is first filter out all `span` rows?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't parse html/xml content with awk/sed tools. 
The right way is using xml/html parsers, like [**xmlstarlet**](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//span[@class="value-style"]' -n index.html | grep -o '[^[:space:]]*'
```

The output:

```
1000
2000
3000
```

---

- `//span[@class="value-style"]` - xpath expression to select only `span` tags (with specified attribute `class`) values
- `grep -o '[^[:space:]]*'` - extract non-whitespace values from the output